# (C#) unescape string

Tags: c#, escaping, fileinfo

i have the following piece of code:

`string fFileName = @txtSelectedFolder.Text + "\\" + file.Name;`

txtSelectedFolder.text contains nothing more than a path to a folder (for example: c:\temp\test)

file.name is a FileInfo type where name contains a reference to the current selected file in a collection of Files.

As soon as i use the above code, my fFileName var is filled with an escaped string like `c:\\temp\\test\filename.ext`

How can i make sure that fFileName contains the unescaped version of the filefolder (and name)

Comment: If you're taking the values from a text box, you're taking the *literal* value of that text box. You don't need to escape/unescape anything. What are you wanting to use the unescaped filename for?

Comment: i need it for a DiscUtils (vhdx) type item which requires a string representation (unescaped) of the complete filepath that i want to open

Also i just fixed the path in my initial question which was wrong

Comment: You're escaping the \\ . Remove the `... + "\\" + ... `

Comment: try this `string fFileName = txtSelectedFolder.Text + @"\" + file.Name;`

Comment: Why is there a `@` before your variable name?

Comment: Use `string fFileName = Path.Combine(txtSelectedFolder.Text, file.Name)`. Where are you seeing “c:\\temp\\test\filename.ext”? In the debugger? The debugger shows escaped strings; to see the actual characters click the Text Visualizer (the magnifying glass icon) in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks Andrey, but i just found out (thanks to your comment) that the problem is with the selectfolder dialog box i have to get the path into the txtSelectedFolder.text field. That is already an escaped string....

Comment: @DourHighArch thanks that indeed gives me the correct data i need (unescaped) so there basicly is another problem in my code why discutils gives me a file not found error.
I'm going to search on. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't using a literal when adding in the extra wacks (`\`) . This will mean your string will escape the `\` as it's being compiled and leave you with a single wack.

Alter your line:

```
string fFileName = @txtSelectedFolder.Text + "\\" + file.Name;
```

to

```
string fFileName = txtSelectedFolder.Text + @"\" + file.Name;
```

You don't need the `@` literal symbol infront of your variable.

Alternatively:

You can instead use

```
string fFileName = Path.Combine(txtSelectedFolder.Text, file.Name);
```

to properly concatenate the file's name to the selected file's path.

Comment: unless variable is named with an @

Comment: @AndreyKaplun since when can a variable start with `@`?

Comment: @maccettura it is possible that's what i am saying try it yourself  when you want to use a keyword you use the `@` symbol ex.`@true`

Comment: @AndreyKaplun the `@` symbol allows you to use _reserved_ keywords as identifiers, `txtSelectedFolder` is not a _reserved_ keyword in C# so therefore the `@` is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `Uri.UnescapeDataString` if using .net 5 or later

Read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.unescapedatastring?view=net-5.0), example below:

```cs
   var unescapedPath = Uri.UnescapeDataString("\\\\server\\dir1\\dir2");
   Console.WriteLine(unescapedPath);
   // \\server\dir1\dir2
```